# How to get a div to auto resize properly horizontally for every screen size/resolution?

Tags: css, html

I am having trouble getting the grey box on my page, https://com-bb-dev.com.edu to automatically resize to the width of the borders on the two boxes that are above it on every resolution. On 1440x900 it looks normal, or how I want it to look for every user, however I am using my second monitor here on a different resolution to test for issues such as this.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#loginText {
padding: 12px 80px 18px 80px;
background: #5f6062;
display: inline-block;
width: 912px;
border-top: 6px solid #DADADA;
margin-left: 10.6%;
text-align: center;
}
```

By default this div is not displaying as an inline box. Its entire container for whatever reason takes up the entire width of the screen(this is by default as far as I know). Thank you.

Comment: You have a SSL error on that site...

Comment: That is because it is our development instance of Blackboard. It does not have a SSL certificate that is valid since we only use it for internal testing purposes. It is safe I can assure you...

Comment: try adding media query in your css file for this element, or set width to 60%, and margin: 0 auto;
`
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#loginText {
 width: 600px
}
}`

Comment: I love the "go away, you have cookies disabled" page.  There's not enough information here to make this question useful to future users when the linked page goes away.  You need to create a simplified test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I went to fix it but broke the site -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the following changes to the #loginText CSS:

```
Remove padding-right: 80px;
Remove padding-left: 80px;
Change margin-right: auto;
Change margin-left: auto;
Add width: 1072px;
```

Your issue is that your margins were percentage based, which scales on all resolutions.  Your box above is an absolute size (1072px); this should make it match and center it as well.

Comment: I've restored access to the site. I am not affiliated with the NSA in any way :)

Comment: Made an edit with the correct size - this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to ask. The reason why the width of the gray box doesn't always match that of the two above boxes is because while the upper boxes have a set width, the gray box resizes with the browser window width (since it has a percentage margin on both sides).

Amend your style definition to this:

```
#loginText {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5F6062;
    border-top: 6px solid #DADADA;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1072px;
}
```

And I believe that gives you the behaviour you're seeking. If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: I wanted to test this since you put in the effort to reply, and it also does work. I just already implement the other answer though. I wish I had enough reputation to up vote your answer! Thank you Serlite.